# Black & Scholes under stochastic interest rate (Vasicek)

Tags: black-scholes, pricing, vasicek

I'm a beginner in Quantitative finance and I'd like to ask you for help about this exercise. I have to price a put option on a risky asset by working under stochastic interest rate, so I have to calibrate this process with simulate data, hence price this derivative.
Could someone help me with a practical exemple, in order to understand? Thanks.

Comment: What precisely is your problem? The pricing of the option? The intuition of the model? The calibration to find the parameters?

Comment: Hello Davide and welcome to SE. Your question needs a bit of focus: what is the issue here? Is it with the calibration of the interest rates model or with the pricing of the put option in the presence of stochastic rates, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to price a European option under a stochastic short rate, you can take a look at the Bakshi, Cao and Chen (1997) paper. Some of their model combine stochastic volatility, jumps in the price process, as well as a stochastic short rate process -- such as what you ask.

The convenience of their approach is that all of their models imply that the conditional characteric function of the price process under the risk-neutral measure is exponentially affine meaning you can price European options using the inverse Fourrier Transform -- no Monte Carlo simulation required! You'll find all the equations you need to code everything on your own in that paper.

Now, if you aren't obligated to do this, I would advise against wasting time on this issue. The reason is that while it is important to recognize that interest rates obey a term structure (i.e., depending on the time to maturity of the option you price, you should definitely use a different interest rate), the uncertainty surrounding changes in the short rate process is insignificant when it comes to pricing an option, not to mention the fact that your short rate process is bound to be misspecified. In all the academic papers you will find, here is what people do:

```
when you price an option with X days to maturity, you look for something like 
a US Treasury bond with as close a maturity as possible and you use the yield 
on that bond as your interest rate.
```

Most of them will also not bother trying to find adequate proxies for the expected dividend yield. They'll just impose put-call parity, derive implies futures prices and use these to price options.